# How to pass the GRAPH variable into FROM statement in SPARQL?

Tags: graph, sparql

I defined a variable ?import which contains URN Graph names

```
SELECT ?import
FROM <urn:xxx:yyy>
WHERE  { <urn:xxx:yyy>  a owl:Ontology; owl:imports ?import. }
```

So this is a content of the variable `?import`:

```
<urn:aaa:wed>
<urn:aaa:ert>
<urn:aaa:cvb>
```

As I want to import all graphs from the variable `?import` to another query I want to put it into the `FROM` statement of another query. In this case I'm getting syntactical error. What is the right way to use the graph variable in another query and how to connect these queries?

Comment: showing the query that fails would help. But, you cannot put variables into the dataset definition part of a query (the `FROM` and `FROM NAMED` part). The only way you can use variables is when using it in the graph patern, i.e. `GRAPH ?import { ...  }`

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "import all graphs" - are those graphs in the triple store already? What about the transitive closure of the OWL import mechanism then? In that case you have to adapt the query and use a property path `owl:imports*`

Comment: yes, all of those graphs in the variable import are already uploaded to Jena Fuseki and instead. so instead of getting them from FROM statement I want to save them in the `GRAPH ?import { ...  }`. I'm already using owl:import to read out the import statement from ontology <urn:xxx:yyy> . The ontology <urn:xxx:yyy> already imports all graphs that I need in ?import